# Why winston logs the error message twice in the same error?

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

EDIT: apparently it's a known issue with winston: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/1739

I have a Node server that keeps logs in files, a mongoDB and shows them in console while in development.

When I throw an error with:

```
throw new Error("The error message.");
```

winston logs the error as follows:

```
2020-02-24 12:20:19 - error: "The error message.The error message."
```

As you can see, the message string is duplicated. Why? All my logs have the same duplication issue.

I tried to play around with the format, but with no avail. Any help is appreciated!

My code:

```
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require("winston");
require("winston-mongodb");
require("express-async-errors");

// Manually throwing the exception will let winston handle the logging
process.on("unhandledRejection", (ex) => {
  throw ex;
});

// Log to files
const logger = createLogger({
  level: "verbose",
  format: format.combine(
    format.timestamp({
      format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
    }),
    format.errors({ stack: true }),
    format.splat(),
    format.json()
  ),
  transports: [
    new transports.File({filename: "./logs/combined.log", level: "verbose"}),
  ],
  transports: [
    new transports.File({filename: "./logs/error.log", level: "error"}),
    new transports.File({filename: "./logs/combined.log"}),
  ],
  exceptionHandlers: [
    new transports.File({ filename: "./logs/exceptions.log" }),
    new transports.File({ filename: "./logs/combined.log" }),
  ],
  handleExceptions: true,
});

// Log to database
logger.add(new transports.MongoDB({
  db: "mongodb://localhost:27017/rest-api-mongodb",
  options: {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
  },
  metaKey: "stack",
}));

// This is used to make the console logging more readable
// Enabled only in development
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" || process.env.NODE_ENV === undefined) {
  const consoleFormat = format.printf(function(info) {
    //console.log(info);
    return `${info.timestamp} - ${info.level}: ${JSON.stringify(info.message, null, 4)}`;
  });

  logger.add(new transports.Console({
    format: format.combine(
      format.colorize(),
      format.timestamp({
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
      }), consoleFormat),
    level: "debug",
    handleExceptions: true,
    colorize: true,
    prettyPrint: true
  }));
}

module.exports = logger;
```

Answer (score 1):

At the point you call winston.error do not pass two arguments only the error object:
e.g. winston.error(err).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is pretty poor behaviour.

My workaround (for my very basic use case) is to hard code the message string, knowing that winston will pull and concatenate the message from the stack anyway:

```
logger.error("Uncaught async err: ", err);
```

Should yield

```
2020-02-24 12:20:19 - error: "Uncaught async err: The error message."
```

This is not great because I'm relying on the poor behaviour to work around it. If it gets fixed I will have to adjust my logging.